# How can we say load is static in case of simple tension test if it is changing with time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

In simple tension test the load acting is static load(which doesn't change with time), but in this test the load varies with time i.e., the load increases, so how can we say it is a static load test?

Comment: Which test? By static is meant 'nothing moves'. It's not about the time evolution of the force(s).

Answer (score 1):

By static, it means slowly changing with time. It is the case of a standard uniaxial tensile test.

One example of the opposite is the Charpy test, where a notched sample is broken by a weight in a pendular movement. If the same weight were just placed slowly on the same test specimen, it is possible that it didn't break.

Answer (score 0):

In a *static test*, the load is nearly constant and acts in only one direction. In a *dynamic test*, the load varies rapidly and can act in both directions i.e., for example in *reversed bending*.

Static tests are used to determine yield point, ultimate strength, etc. and dynamic tests are used to determine fatigue resistance and vibrational dynamics.